# Notion of variables in GraphQL

Tags: graphql

We would like to be able to use parts of the query result as a variable further in the same query. This does not seem to be present in the GraphQL language.

For example, we have a knowledge graph where we are looking for timeseries measurements from a temperature sensor during a curing operation. The key problem is that we need to indicate what the start and end time is of the curing operation in order to obtain the temperature at the time period of the curing operation.

What I expect a single-query intuitive way to do this, would be to declare variables `$start` and `$end` and use them later as follows:

```
{
    products {
        serialnumber,
        operation(type:"Curing") {
            name,
            $start: start,
            $end: end,
            measurement(from:$start, to:$end){
                timestamp,
                value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only way to get a result for such a query is to split up in two separate queries. First to obtain the start and end time **per product**:

```
{
    products {
        serialnumber,
        operation(type:"Curing") {
            name,
            $start: start,
            $end: end
        }
    }
}
```

Second to obtain the correct measurements, a second query will need to be asked **per product** based on the response of the previous query. The following template can be used:

```
{
    product(serialnumber:"{SERIALNUMBER}") {
        serialnumber
        operation(name:"{OPERATION}") {
            measurement(from:"{START}", to:"{END}"){
                timestamp,
                value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(Note that similarly, a GraphQL query with "variables" can be used here - which act as parameters but do not provide a way to express the single query approach.)

This seems to negate the benefits of GraphQL, namely being able to specify what you need in a single query, and obtaining a single, well-structured query response.

Are there any ways in GraphQL to use variables, or anything that allows you to use a single query for the scenario above?

Edit: @xadm replied with a solution that would work when we can assume that we *always* want to use the operations' start and end time. This is not the case, so the above is a misleading example. An extension of the example below (although a bit contrived) fits better what we need:

Suppose a number of time stamps are recorded during the curing operation:

- ovenTurnOn: time when turning on the oven (preheating starts)
- openOvenStart: time when opening the oven door to move in the products
- closeOvenStart: time when the door is shut, with the products inside
- curingStart: time when the curing operation starts, and the temperature profile for curing is followed
- curingEnd: time when the curing has finished
- openOvenEnd: time when the oven is opened to take out the cured products
- closeOvenEnd: time when the oven is closed again
- ovenTurnOff: time when the oven is turned off

We may be interested in temperature measurements between any of these times, e.g.,

- to look into the temperature profile during curing (between curingStart and curingEnd)
- to look into the heat dissipation when opening the door (between openOvenStart and closeOvenStart, or openOvenEnd and closeOvenEnd)
  etc.

One example could look like this, but many variants for defining `$start` and `$end` are possible and need to be determined by the person making the *query*, not the pre-fixed *resolver* for `measurement`:

```
{
    products {
        serialnumber,
        operation(type:"Curing") {
            name,
            ovenTurnOn,
            $start: openOvenStart,
            closeOvenStart,
            curingStart,
            curingEnd,
            $end: openOvenEnd,
            closeOvenEnd,
            ovenTurnOff,
            measurement(from:$start, to:$end){
                timestamp,
                value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `measurement` resolver gets `parent` as 1st arg (in majority of implementations) and can access `parent.name`, `parent.start`/etc (from `operation`, if used as its child in the query 'tree'). without using variables at all ... don't use `$` sign/char in query 'body' (for names), usage restricted to variables

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer @xadm. It will work for the example, but I am looking for a way to let the person writing the query choose what variables to use. Since my example is not good for showing this, I extended it in the original post.